# Once an editor has become read only no formatting can happen, even if switched back to read only = false

Tags: vuejs3, monaco-editor

On my onMounted function I call my init function:
the editor code is only formatting after changes have made, for example I add a console log, and save, after that the formatting happens. and the formatting should happen on mount. I am aware of [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/978)

```
 editor.getAction('editor.action.formatDocument').run().then(() => console.log('finished'));
```

But this only works when I save something. and not onMounted.

```
const init = async () => {
  monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
    noSemanticValidation: true,
    noSyntaxValidation: false,
  })
  monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
    target: monaco.languages.typescript.ScriptTarget.ES2020,
    allowNonTsExtensions: true,
  })

  editor = monaco.editor.create(codeEditorBox.value, {
    value: props.value,
    language: props.language,
    theme: props.theme,
    ...props.options,
  })

  if (editor !== null) {
    await editor
      ?.getAction('editor.action.formatDocument')
      ?.run()
      .then(() => console.log('finished'))
  }

  editor.onDidChangeModelContent(() => {
    const value = editor.getValue()
    emit('update:value', value)
    emit('change', value)
  })

  emit('editor-mounted', editor)
}
```

How I call my function:

```
onMounted(() => {
  init()
})
```